# Why two arrays are "equal" for getter when they have the same values?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to have a custom getter and setter method for my object which wraps `Map`.
Somehow when I use arrays as a key `getter` behaves as they are equal when they have the same values. Even though they are two different references. (tested in FF and Chrome).

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/dftc2tx3/3/)

```
var Cons = function (){
  this.data = new Map();
};

Cons.prototype.initialiseGetterAndSetter = function initialiseGetterAndSetter(prop){
  Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
    get: function(){
      return this.data.get(prop);
    },
    set: function(val){
      this.data.set(prop, val);
    }
  });
};

var obj = new Cons();

var arr1 = [1];
var arr2 = [1];
var arr3 = [2];

obj.initialiseGetterAndSetter(arr1);

obj[arr1] = 1;

document.getElementById('box1').innerText = obj[arr1]; // 1 as expected
document.getElementById('box2').innerText = obj[arr2]; // expected undefined but got 1
document.getElementById('box3').innerText = obj[arr3]; // undefined as expected
```

As you can see it doesn't matter if what you pass to the getter it the same reference which I was expecting. It only checks if it has the same values which is kind a strange for me. Could you explain me why it behaves that way?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**
When you access map directly it returns expected results.

Comment: It probably converts the key to a string and uses `'1'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Object property names can only be string values. When you call `Object.defineProperty()`, it will coerce your `prop` value to a string (in which case `arr1` and `arr2` are both coerced to the same value.

The same happens when you try to access the object properties using `obj[arr1]` and `obj[arr2]`.

If you want your object to expose a map, then give it members that access that map. Object properties don't work the way you are trying to use them:

```
var Cons = function (){
  this.data = new Map();

  this.get = function (key) { return this.data.get(key); };
  this.set = function (key, value) { this.data.set(key, value); };
};


// further down...

obj.set(arr1, 1);
```

Comment: yep that's the reason. The strange part of that happens when I `console.log(prop)` in getter it display array but in that case it should log string. https://jsfiddle.net/dftc2tx3/4/

Comment: That's not strange. Your `console.log()` line is accessing the actual `prop` value that's in the scope of the `get` and `set` closures, the one that was originally passed into `initialiseGetterAndSetter()`.

Answer (score 2):

Property names on JavaScript objects are strings, when you use something other than a string as a name, it is first converted to a string.

`arr1` and `arr2` are both arrays with the contents of `[1]`, when you `toString()` this, you get `"1"`.

The array in `arr3` will similarly get you `"2"`.  Thus `arr1` and `arr2` map to the same property, with the name `"1"`, while `arr3` goes to a different one.